# Update Docker to latest version

Tags: docker

Is there any available APT on where I can download the latest version of Docker? Latest version is around **~1.17**, mine shows **1.12** only.

```
boozer@useless-pc:/etc/apt/sources.list.d $ sudo apt-get install docker.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
docker.io is already the newest version (1.12.6-0ubuntu1~16.04.1).
```